# Motivations for long therm

Tags: bodybuilding

I want to start working out and would like to ask you what is your motivation?

What is that! Thing that keeps you going and performing every day..

Comment: Stack exchange is for questions that have specific correct answers. It is not a forum for sharing personal thoughts and experiences. For more information, please go to the [help].

Comment: You say that you "want to start working out", so you seem to have some motivation already.  You might try Starting Strength if you'd like to get stronger.  Ultimately, you probably will not persevere in the long term unless you are motivate from _within yourself_.

Comment: This is just soliciting opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a Female, and from my experience, what makes me very motivated to do work out every day, is just I have a look on the pictures of  fitted girls posted on social  media.  Then watch some videos  for those fitted  girls  doing differnt exercises with thier  flexible bodies, then nothing can keep me sitting on my chair  !

Comment: If you have some links that you used in the beginning, please share them here, it would be helpful